# Android: using image instead of text on a button

Tags: android, image, button, insert

I've been working on my android calculator and i can't seem to insert an image instead of text on a button. For example sqrt I don't want to have sqrt written on my button i want the image of the symbol on it, the same goes for x^y and alot of others. I have my custom background of the button working just fine. Thank you for your help in advance :)

EDIT:
Thats not what i wanted i did manage to get my custom button and thats fine. On my button since its a calculator button i have android:text on it saying sqrt. I want to remove that and insert another png on my button showing the symbol of the square root instead of that text. Thank you for quick responses.

Comment: So change from `Button` to `ImageButton` and you can set background or src attribute to your image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/imageName"/>
```

You can have both text and image (or no text) when using the attribute `drawableTop`, `drawableBottom`, `drawableLeft` and `drawableRight`.

And for positioning the image how you want, consider using: `paddingTop`, `paddingBottom`, `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight`.

Comment: If i use that the symbol will be not in the center :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by ImageButton:

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/submitEmailButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_submit" />
```

Here ic_submit is the image you want to show as a button.

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial and it worked perfectly for me: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

I haven't seen your code but basically you should remove the "text" tag from your xml and it should appear the image without text then.

I don't know if that's exactly what you were looking for or not, but I reccomend you to follow the tutorial and for sure it will work for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of alternatives you can try to implement to build your SQRT button:

- draw the button as a 9-patch drawable so your SQRT symbol won't get distorted;
- use a RelativeLayout with a button inside and implement a selector

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set background for the Button and keep its text blank.